# Angular ui-router and Google autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, google-places

I have created a ui-router based tabs. One of them has a google autocomplete input.

```
.state('manage', {
  templateUrl: "/templates/pages/issues/manage.html",
  controller: 'IssueManageController'
})
.state('manage.tab', {
  url: "/manage/:tab",
  templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
    return '/templates/pages/forms/' + $stateParams.tab + '.html';
  },
});
```

tabs panel generator

```
<ul class="form--tabs">
  <li ng-repeat="tab in TABS" ui-sref="manage.tab({tab: tab.template})" ui-sref-active="selected" ng-class="{'selected': isSelected($index)}"><span>{{tab.title}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

the template with autocomplete code

```
<input type="text" id="googleplace" ng-model="form.object.fullAddress">
...
...
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('googleplace');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
</script>
```

After filling out the input some tabs' templates becomes blank without any errors. It's always the same templates. Also the problem is not reproducing in firefox but there is the problem in Safari and Chrome.

**Added....**

The problem is in the nested routes. When I changed the routes to the direct states like .state('profile'), .state('location') ... and added wrapper code from manage.html to each of templates problem not reproduced.

But it's not a solution I think. A lot of code repeated.

Comment: Adding adhoc script tags in angular is generally not a good idea. They should be enclosed in an angular directive.  This may be the cause

Comment: I tried with directive and had the same issue

Comment: It was the directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969263/scope-variable-doesnt-set/34969348#34969348